# How to transform MongoDB document to array

Tags: arrays, mongodb

My returned Document looks like this:

```
{
    "_id": "57terjrtgutgsjj",
    "eventList": [
        {
            "eventId": "5346a816e4b0efc8bd9759b5",
            "riskScore": 0,
            "entity": {
                "entityId": "5346a816e4b0efc8bd9759b6",
                "name": "src ip",
                "value": "209.178.49.9",
                "type": "IP",
                "direction": "S",
                "isKey": "true"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I want result in this format:

```
{
    "_id": "57terjrtgutgsjj",
    "eventList": [
        {
            "eventId": "5346a816e4b0efc8bd9759b5",
            "riskScore": 0,
            "entity": [
                {
                    "entityId": "5346a816e4b0efc8bd9759b6",
                    "name": "src ip",
                    "value": "209.178.49.9",
                    "type": "IP",
                    "direction": "S",
                    "isKey": "true"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The difference between first and second document is that the "entity" field is a simple document in first case whereas it is an array in second case.
So is it possible to convert a simple document to one of the elements inside array.Obviously there will be only one object inside that array, that doesn't matter to the requirements.So can anyone please tell if this is possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What programming language are you using? I'd suggest fixing it on the client if you can't change the storage code to store it as an array.

Answer (score 0):

I would question whether you actually do want to do this and take a good look at the [positional `$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) operator documentation for the reason why nested arrays are generally not good news if you want to update them.

But if you decide you really want to do this then the following form will suit, noting that you of course need to actually obtain the document content first and otherwise use the [**`$unset`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/) operator:

```js
db.collection.find({ "_id": "57terjrtgutgsjj" }).forEach(function(doc) {
    db.collection.update(
        { "_id": doc._id },
        { "$unset": { "entity": 1 } }
    );
    db.collection.update(
        { "_id": doc._id },
        { "$push": { "entity": doc.entity } }        
    ); 
)
```

So one update, well no. You can actually get some help with ["bulk updates"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/update/#bulk-update) available from the 2.6 release of MongoDB, but the benefit is somewhat negated by the way you need to process this in bulk. It could be applied, but you should be able to see the sort of coding pattern that would need to be used.